# Count number of incoming connection on a port - Linux

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, syn

We have a server which listens on port X. The server has a large number of clients, from time to time the process gets hung, I am seeing SYN flooding messages in the log. I have been trying to tune relevant tcp configuration params.

I would like a way to count number of incoming connections to that particular port using tcpdump or another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iptables can log connections or if you prefer you can use the `--tcp-flags SYN` option to match syn packets.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport <listenPort> \
    -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix 'PORTMON'

grep 'PORTMON' /var/log/messages
```

`netstat` can show active connections (pipe to `wc -l` for counts):

```
netstat -punta | grep <yourPort>
```

Or just use tcpdump to examine the traffic.

`man tcpdump`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a network monitoring solution?

It's not just getting the number of connections to that port, is doing something is the value is too high: like setting and iptables rule to ban an IP, or getting an alert to your cellphone . As stated in [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/775631/350203), you can use the IPTraf plugin of **Pandora FMS** to get that metric, and then use the alerting and reporting capabilities of Pandora FMS to do something about it.